# Fullscreen photo at surfaceview

Tags: android, fullscreen, surfaceview

I need onTouchFocus Fullscreen surfaceview like in this example: 
https://github.com/jayrambhia/Touch2Focus
But it works fine only in Landscape orientation (surfaceview changes resolution in portrait mode not so fine as at standart android camera app).
Any ideas how to fix it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `onCreate()`

```
 Window window = getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        else
            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This will set your Activity Window Fullscreen like the Android Camera App.
Also, I am doing following in `surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)` method:

```
        if (height > width)
            _camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        else
            _camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

        // Setting BestPreviewSize for Current Pixels
        Camera.Parameters p = _camera.getParameters();

        Camera.Size size = null;
        List<Camera.Size> list = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        size = list.get(0);

        for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if((list.get(i).width * list.get(i).height) > (size.width * size.height))
            size = list.get(i);
        }

        if(size != null) {
            p.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            _camera.setParameters(p);
        }
        _camera.startPreview();
```

This gets a list of supported preview sizes and chooses the one closest to the screen size, and setting that as a `Camera Parameter`.
Cheers `:)`